# Firestore.Query.GetSnapshotAsync() never returns and doesn't give any errors - the program just doesn't stop

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a game in Unity version 2019.4.1f1 (LTS) and i'm using Firebase Firestore database. 
Basically when I try to fetch the user from the database, specifically when i'm calling `GetSnapshotAsync()`, it gets stuck. 
The hierarchy is as follows: 
`StartState` calls `FetchUserState` which calls `DBGetObjectState` which communicates with `DatabaseManager` (`DatabaseManager` contains the line where `GetSnapshotAsync()` gets called).

Would be really nice if someone could help me figure out this problem.
Thank you for helping!

class **FetchUserState**

```
//fetch user by userId
            await stateManager.PushTempState(new DBGetObjectState<T>(StringConstants.DB_USERS_COLLECTION, //("Users")
                field: "UserId", fieldEqualTo: _userId, withLoading: false));
```

class **DBGetObjectState**

```
Log("Getting Documents");
var documents = await DatabaseManager.GetDocuments<T>(_path, _limit, _orderBy, _orderByDescending, _field, _fieldEqualTo);
Log("Got something, checking..."); // doesn't get here
```

class **DatabaseManager**

```
public static async Task<Collection<T>> GetDocuments<T>(string path, int limit = -1,
        string orderBy = null, string orderByDescending = null, string field = null, object fieldEqualTo = null)
    {
        var collectionRef = DBUtills.GetCollectionRef(path);

        Query query = collectionRef;

        if (field != null && fieldEqualTo != null)
            query = query.WhereEqualTo(field, fieldEqualTo);
        if (orderBy != null)
            query = query.OrderBy(orderBy);
        if (orderByDescending != null)
            query = query.OrderByDescending(orderByDescending);
        if (limit >= 0)
            query = query.Limit(limit);

        Debug.Log("Snapshotting!");
        QuerySnapshot collectionSnapshot = await query.GetSnapshotAsync();
        Debug.Log("got a snapshot, checking..."); // doesn't get here
        
        //....
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your callbacks are executed on the Unity main thread? Rather try something like [`ContinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension)

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for helping, you're absolutely right, that was it. Guess i'll use that from now on.

Comment: Please, add the solution as an answer in the thread, it will help the community member to check the solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to anyone who tried to help, apparently it was a plugin that I used for handling tasks, I should've checked it first before even asking the question.
Anyways, if someone still experiences an issue, @derHugo's answer was definitely a solution, instead of awaiting the task, simply use `ContinueWithOnMainThread()` to create a callback that will be called after the task is finished, like that:

```
query.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
{
   if(task.IsFaulted)
   {
       //....
   }
   QuerySnapshot collectionSnapshot = task.Result;
   //....
}
```